# How to run e2e tests if Angular project is generated in NX workspace with preset "empty"?

Tags: angular, e2e-testing, nrwl-nx

If you create an NX workspace with preset `angular`, you can run e2e tests successfully using `yarn e2e`

```
yarn create nx-workspace start-angular --preset=angular --appName=web --packageManager=yarn --nx-cloud=false --style=scss --routing --viewEncapsulation=Emulated --enableIvy --unitTestRunner=jest --e2eTestRunner=cypress --linter=eslint
cd start-angular
yarn e2e
```

However, if you create a workspace with preset `empty` and add an Angular project later (e.g. to be able to pass additional options like `--strict`),

```
yarn create nx-workspace start-empty --preset empty --packageManager=yarn --nx-cloud=false
cd start-empty
yarn add --dev @nrwl/angular
yarn nx generate @nrwl/angular:application --name=web --strict --style=scss --routing --viewEncapsulation=Emulated --enableIvy --unitTestRunner=jest --e2eTestRunner=cypress --linter=eslint
yarn e2e
```

you get the following error when you run e2e tests (output of `yarn e2e`):

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ nx e2e
No project name specified. Using default project : web
​
 ERROR  Cannot find target 'e2e' for project 'web'
​
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How to change the configuration in the workspace `start-empty` to be able to run e2e tests using `yarn e2e`? You can run `yarn e2e web-e2e`, but I don't understand, why `yarn e2e` is not working in NX workspace `start-empty` but in `start-angular`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `nx e2e web-e2e`? This is the name of the default e2e project that is created for an app with the name `web` when you run the `nx generate @nrwl/angular:application` schematic. Indeed, in your `workspace.json` there will be no `e2e` target for the project `web`, but there will be one for the `web-e2e` project which is the e2e project you want to run!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `nx e2e web-e2e` works as well as `yarn e2e web-e2e`. However, I'd like to know, why I can not run `yarn e2e` in `start-empty` but in `start-angular`. I just realized that there is no `workspace.json` in `start-angular`, but if I delete `workspace.json` in `start-empty` and run `yarn e2e`, I get another error: "The current directory isn't part of an Nx workspace". Why do I not get this error in `start-angular`, which does not have a `workspace.json` initially.